# Strange recent items when attaching to Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I often save files on my windows 10 PC, open outlook (office 365). Then I click the attach item paperclip and down drops a list of recent items. At the top of the list is always the file I have just saved. This is perhaps an excel spreadsheet or word document or a notepad file or something, it doesn't matter what it is.

Today this didn't happen. Instead the dropdown contained a list of files from my appdata folder that I definitely haven't accessed. See the picture below.

I have opened up a new windows explorer folder and expected to see the same items in Quick access but this looked normal with my most recently accessed files, as I would expect. Does anyone have any idea what would have accessed these files and should I be concerned?

[image: snapshot of recent items in outlook.]

Comment: Try clearing Quick Access, restart the computer and test again. To clear Quick Access:  Open Windows Explorer, Right Click on Quick Access (top left), select Options,  then click on the Clear button. Close out, restart and test

Comment: Thank you for your comment but my question wasn't how to clear the list, it was why are they in the list? What has accessed them if it wasn't me and should I be concerned?

Comment: I understand but my suggestion to clear the list was to restart the list the way you are used to.